# How do I get the rendered web page page from a URL?

Tags: java

I don't want just the source code. I want the rendered page. This is an important distinction that I apparently cannot make by simply searching Google.

Does anyone know how I can get the **rendered** page from a URL?

This needs to be done in Java, hopefully without an extra library.

Comment: use a browser and go to the url?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a library that wraps a web browser, for example [Berkelium](http://berkelium.org/). If you need it in Java, a Google search produced [this Java wrapper API for Berkelium](http://code.google.com/p/berkelium-java/) (I haven't tried it personally).

sites.google has an [example](https://sites.google.com/site/berkeliumjava/examples/awt) of its use:

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use [`HTMLUnit`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) which is a "GUI-less browser for JAVA".  It is recommended by Google to generate snapshots of ajax-based webpages to make them crawlable.

Comment: I am a little confused. This looks like it has to be a JUnit test. Am I right?

Comment: It can be used for unit testing yes but it can also be used to get a rendered HTML page (a snapshot).  I have been working on websites that use Ajax and HTMLUnit has allowed me to generate snapshots of my webpages that I would output to make the website crawlable.   [This](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot) page shows an example of how a snapshot can be generated using HTMLUnit at point 3 near the bottom of the page.  Hope this helps!